# how do I render PyChart.JS charts in web2py?

Tags: python, chart.js, web2py, pychart

So I'm trying to make use of the PyChartJS module and so far I have this.
This is the class for the PieChart:

```
class newPieChart(BaseChart):

def setData(self, _data: dict):
    self.data.data = [_ for _ in _data.values()]
    return

def setLabels(self, _labels: list):
    self.labels.labels = [_ for _ in _labels]
    return

type = ChartType.Pie

class labels:
    labels = []

class data:
    data = []
```

And I'm using `setData()` to fill the chart with data

```
{'Allowance': 20.0, 'Bonus': 30.0, 'Other': 80.0, 'Salary': 300.0}
```

Now, whenever I try `newPieChart.get()` I get the JSON back needed for the render in JS. This is what it returns:

```
{'type': 'pie', 'data': {'labels': [], 'datasets': [{'data': [20.0, 30.0, 80.0, 300.0]}]}, 'options': {'plugins': {}}}
```

The chart however doesn't render, as this is how it shows up in my JS code:

```
{&#x27;type&#x27;: &#x27;pie&#x27;, &#x27;data&#x27;: {&#x27;labels&#x27;: [], &#x27;datasets&#x27;: [{&#x27;data&#x27;: [20.0, 30.0, 80.0, 300.0]}]}, &#x27;options&#x27;: {&#x27;plugins&#x27;: {}}}
```

My question is, how do I render this chart correctly? How do I fix this?
This is how I implemented it in my JavaScript code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('expense').getContext('2d');
var expensechart = new Chart(ctx, {{=chart}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by calling the built-in `XML()` helper

```
var expensechart = new Chart(ctx, {{=XML(chart)}})
```

This fixes the issue of JSON not rendering correctly inside the HTML